# How can I make my span properly aligned as I toggle another element?

Tags: javascript, css, html

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRWBA/), I am trying to create a DIV that expands and collapses as you click its title.  The title is positioned on the top border, almost like a legend tag of a fieldform.  I would like for the top border of the DIV to remain when the box is collapsed.

If you check out my jsfiddle, you'll see it functions pretty well.  However, the border of my container box must be turned off in order to achieve this effect.  As a result, the contents of my title shift to the left.  They are shifting the same amount of pixels that the left border of the outer DIV was in width.

I've tried a few things to compensate for the shift because I would like for the text to remain in the same position while the top border remains in its original position as well, but no luck so far.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This one** lets the legend stay where it is but cuts the border on the left and right side:

```css
.boxContainerHidden {
    padding-left:        0px;
    border:              2px solid transparent;
    border-top-width:    0px;
}
```

Try it: **[forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/G6EbT/)**

**This one** lets the legend stay at its position and does not cut the border:

```css
.boxContainerHidden {
   height:           1px;
   border:           solid #ffffff;
   border-width:     2px;
   border-top-width: 0px;
   border-bottom:    0px;
}
```

Try it too: **[forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/BdeG7/)**

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest. Instead of removing the border, just make it transparent to keep the same pixel dimensions.

Comment: It's true your solution stops the text from moving.  However, I'd like the top border to be the same size collapsed and expanded.  Right now it's two pixels short on the left side and right side each.  Is what I want possible?

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer with a possible solution (hope I got you right).

Comment: You did understand me correctly this time.  Great solution.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

i think if you put the text inside #mdlFcstContent in a span. then set the span to display:none; instead of doing it the way you are doing it, your problem will be solved

```
<div id='mdlFcstContent'>
    <span id='mdlFcstContent_span'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer venenatis vitae Nulla fringilla consequat. Wisi magnis volutpat auctor Nulla Vivamus id In elit dictumst mollis. Curabitur auctor consectetuer dui interdum neque Curabitur vel auctor tellus netus. Sed tincidunt condimentum semper Vestibulum sed tellus ridiculus elit In dictum. Turpis lacus pellentesque In ac volutpat mi non nibh vitae laoreet. Elit.
    </span>
</div>
```

then put this in your toggle function

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('mdlFcstContent_span');
 elem.style.display = "none";
```

edit: i noticed, these leaves a bottom border as well, not sure if this is a deal breaker for you.  if it is, instead of removing the border, just set the color to transparent

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/EekzW/3/

You have to add `display:inline-block` to the span because the `margin` property doesn't work on non-block elements

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my problem clearly.  I would like for the top border to appear the same size collapsed and expanded.  Right now it's two pixels shorter on each side thanks to the left and right borders being gone.  Maybe what I want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

@insertusernamehere gave a great answer, but I found another solution that I figured I would post too:  **[forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvB7k/)**

I solved the problem by changing the width of the left border for the SPAN under the boxTitle DIV when the DIV is collapsed.

**EDIT:** This is the most practical solution in my opinion.  It allows you to easily change the width of the borders from 2 pixels to 1 pixel without a problem.